# Dense coding for PR boxes

Tags: information-theory, superdense-coding

We can think of an entangled state as a resource for accomplishing various tasks. For example, passing a CHSH test, performing a dense coding operation (when enhanced by transmission of a single qubit), teleporting a quantum state (when enhanced by two classical bits of communication).

When it comes to the CHSH test, a quantum resource cannot give the maximum possible theoretical value of $S=4$. Instead, it can achieve up to $S=2\sqrt{2}$ (which is better than the classical limit of $S=2$). However, theorists have suggested examining the consequences of a "PR-box", which is a hypothetical resource which achieves this value of $S=4$.

If I had such a PR box, would I be able to use it for dense coding? How dense is the coding - the same, better, or worse than quantum? I'm guessing that it's not sufficient to talk about a PR box in the abstract: one needs to have a theory in which you can write an equivalent of a state ("generalised probabilistic theory"?) *and* a detailed mechanism for measuring those state equivalents. I know such formalisms exist, but am not familiar with the details.

Comment: What would even be the setup? It is not clear what "sending the other half of the entangled state" would mean for a PR box, nor what the equivalent of LU would be (appending another box to it? -- that might actually work: Alice appends sth. to her part of the box, and then Bob gets to use the entire box once, this seems like a natural analog. Of course, in this setup there is no way to infer more than two bits per use, as the entire output are two bits.). -- There are results how PR boxes can reduce communication complexity, but I'm sure you are aware of those.

Comment: If you just share a single PR box then the answer is no. See Theorem 12 in [Information processing in generalized probabilistic theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0508211). Well at least for the common GPT describing PR boxes, perhaps there are others.